# Disable Nemo windows snap on open?

Tags: nemo

I switched over from Nautilus to Nemo and is slightly annoying every time a window opens its position is snapped along side any other open window. Is there a way to disable this ? Ideally want to remember window positions.
(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

All I have is quit in the app menu and nothing in preferences. Can't find anything In the behaviour / views / display settings relating to opening new windows or tiling. This is really bugging me.

Is there config file I can edit ?

1 thing does have an affect, on the desktop right click - desktop - align to grid. Any new windows open 0 position.

Answer (score 0):

You should have "Window Tiling" config options in your menu. Play around with the settings and see whether disabling snapping works better for you.